# Getting data in Json.Net c#

Tags: c#, json.net

I want to get data from json file correctly. The json data file I modeled for this is as follows:

```
{
    "Free title 1":[
        {
            "Subject": "a1",
            "Relation": "a2"
        },
        {
            "Subject": "b1",
            "Relation": "b2"
        }
    ],
    "Another free title":[
        {
            "Subject": "z1",
            "Relation": "z2"
        },
        {
            "Subject": "y1",
            "Relation": "y2"
        }
    ],
    "Unordered title":[
        {
            "Subject": "x1",
            "Relation": "x2"
        },
        {
            "Subject": "w1",
            "Relation": "w2"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is how I create an object class:

```
public class _Infos_
{
    public List<_Info_> Infos { get; set; }
}
public class _Info_
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Relation { get; set; }
}
```

And finally I'm trying to get the data in a method like this:

```
var js = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<_Infos_>(File.ReadAllText("__FILE_PATH__"));
foreach (var j in js.Infos)
{
    MessageBox.Show(j.Subject);
}
```

I get the error that `js` is empty. Here I want to get `Free title 1`, `Another free title` and `Unordered title` in a list. Of course, these titles will be constantly changing. Afterwards, I want to get the `Subject` and `Relation` data under these titles. But I have no idea how to get it.

Comment: You need something like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<_Info_>>` per outer object member. Else the outer object must have one key with the same name as the property `Infos`. I.e. if you are using dynamic naming, the deserialization will not work like this.

Answer (score 3):

This data structure is a dictionary of collections of `_Info_`s. You need to deserialize it to `Dictionary<string, List<_Info_>>`.

Here are System.Text.Json and Json.net examples:

```
var d = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, List<_Info_>>>(json);

var d2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<_Info_>>>(json);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class definition is a little wrong.
You can use online tools "json to c#" to generate the correct classes.
like this one: https://json2csharp.com

Your "root" of your json for example does not contain an array in your json. The property "Free title 1":[..]  is an array, so your root needs a property with the name FreeTitle1 and it has to be an array/list.

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("Free title 1")]
    public List<TitleInfo> FreeTitle1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Another free title")]
    public List<TitleInfo> AnotherFreeTitle { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Unordered title")]
    public List<TitleInfo> UnorderedTitle { get; set; }
}

public class TitleInfo
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Relation { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the update. Likely the names/keys of the members are not known in advance. How would you in that case approach the issue?

Comment: What if you add another book?

Answer (score 1):

If your object members have dynamic names, you can also manually deserialize the object, e.g. using the general type `JObject`. E.g.

```cs
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("__FILE_PATH__"));
```

`JObject` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>>` over which you can iterate.
Each member will then have `JToken` `Value`, which is a `JArray` in this case, which you can cast to a `List` of your type.

```cs
foreach (var groups in obj)
{
    var infos = groups.Value.ToObject<List<_Info_>>();
    // .. loop over infos
}
```