# Deserialize Json Array of Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, .net

I have an array of dictionaries, after serializing to JSON I get this string:

```
"[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]"
```

I want to make a List of values out of this JSON, how can I achieve this?

Comment: What json handling library do you use?

Comment: I think you might have made a mistake in serializing you values.

Comment: BTW. C# dictionaries don't support duplicate keys.

Comment: Please show us your data model.

Comment: @GuruStron I am using Json.net;

Comment: @JHBonarius I don't know why, because I am doing API calls from a server to another Server, and the serialization happens automatically idk where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is a bit weird, as it's a list with 1 element, that is an object/dictionary... I think you made a mistake with serialization.

But to give you an answer: It's the inverse of what was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71420649)

Here are System.Text.Json and Json.net examples:

```
var d = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(json);

var d2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string,string>>>(json);
```

You can then use the List indexer with `Dictionary.Values` like

```
var values = d[0].Values
```

Note that `values` will be a `Dictionary<string,string>.ValueCollection`, not a list. But it still has an enumerator.
edit: so you could call Linq's `ToList()`.

Comment: Thank u so much! I was expecting a json like this "[{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}]" but idk why It shows up like this.

Answer (score 0):

After you serialization it to a list of dictionaries you can transform it to a list:

```
var d = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(json);
// or Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(json);

List<C> l = d
    .SelectMany(x  => x.Select(kvp => new C(Key: kvp.Key, Value: kvp.Value)))
    .ToList();
```

`C` could look like this:

```
public record C(string Key, string Value);
```